# I need to fix this Tile bug in XNA

Tags: c#, math, xna, game-physics, tiles

I am currently creating a space shooter game. To this game I want a background with stars that keeps looping for eternity.

In order to create this, I made a tile based system that simply creates a rectangle for each texture. I have been able to make said textures kinda loop, but when they do I get a really weird bug.

[image: Image link for that bug]

As you can see, my tiles are sometimes generating a small gap between each other, and I am not sure as of why.

The problem probably lies within my **Background.cs** file, but I am unsure of where.

Also, I would like a better name for "Background.cs". Do you think that something like "Tile.cs" is better?

---

**Background.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace SpaceShooter
{
    class Background
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public List<Rectangle> tiles = new List<Rectangle>();
    public Color color;
    public int tileSize;
    public int speed;
    GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;

    public Background(Texture2D texture, GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, int tileSize)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.graphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;
        this.tileSize = tileSize;
        speed = 3;
        this.color = Color.White;
        CalculateTiles();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.Count(); i++)
        {
            tiles[i] = new Rectangle(tiles[i].X, tiles[i].Y + speed, tiles[i].Width, tiles[i].Height);
            if (tiles[i].Y >= graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height)
            {
                tiles[i] = new Rectangle(tiles[i].X, 0 - tiles[i].Height, tiles[i].Width, tiles[i].Height);
            }
        }
    }

    public void CalculateTiles()
    {
        if (tiles.Count() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tiles.Count(); i++)
            {
                tiles.Remove(tiles[i]);
            }
        }
        int XT = (int)(graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / (tileSize / 1.5f));
        int YT = (int)(graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / (tileSize / 1.5f));
        for (int i = 0; i < XT; i++)
        {
            tiles.Add(new Rectangle(tileSize * i, 0, tileSize, tileSize));

            for (int j = 0; j < YT; j++)
            {
                tiles.Add(new Rectangle(tileSize * i, tileSize * j, tileSize, tileSize));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.Count(); i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, tiles[i], color);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Game.cs**

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    Background background;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Assign Background
        background = new Background(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Stars"),GraphicsDevice, 128);
    }  

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if(Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        background.Update();
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(bgc);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        // Call all drawing functions here 
        background.Draw(spriteBatch);
        player1.Draw(spriteBatch);
        player2.Draw(spriteBatch);
        // 
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem has been solved.**
I am now putting the tile up relative to the screen height instead of raw programming it to 0.

```
            if (tiles[i].Y >= graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height)
            {
                tiles[i] = new Rectangle(tiles[i].X, tiles[i].Y - graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - tiles[i].Height, tiles[i].Width, tiles[i].Height);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be easily solved with **LinearWrap**

if you do the following in your **Game1.draw**.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearWrap);
background.Draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.End();
```

to get the scale simply do this calculation:

```
float scale = 128 / 512; // Where 128 is your desired size. and 512 your actual texture size.
```

and in your **Background.cs** draw method.

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(0,0), new Rectangle(pos.X, pos.Y, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / scale, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / scale), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

this should repeat your texture over the entire screen.

EDIT:

To make the image dynamic you could use a Camera. But using the system you have you would simply on Update do this :

```
pos += new Vector2(movementX, movementY);
```

Note that the spriteBatch.Draw has a parameter "Source Rectangle". If you change the position of this rectangle your texture will shift.

Comment: That it does. However, a still image like that is not what I have as desire for my background.  
I need the background to be tiled so that I can fit it onto any screen, as well as making it pan downwards (create the effect of moving forward).

Comment: @riddarn97 Simply change the X and Y position of the Source Rectangle as shown in my edit this should give you your desired effect.

Comment: Not quite so actually. You see, even though that would make my game pan as I want it to; The rectangle is stretched over the screen, thus, making my 128x128 texture look very, very bad.  

I mean, the physics are there, I am just doing some kind of math wrong here (I think).

Do you think there is a way to use my current tile system to make it work the way I want it to?

Comment: What is the actual size of your stars.png file?

Comment: 512 x 512  
After that I am creating a tile system that covers the screen (These tiles are a list of rectangles that I can dynamically change the size of whenever I feel like it). Then I fill these tiles with my texture.

Comment: Added scale into the answer. Does this resolve your issues?

Comment: That gave me a quite disturbing effect. The entire texture became really really big.

Comment: Maybe I should just use a black background and have the stars be objects that are flying down the screen?  
Would that be really demanding from my processor, or is it a good idea?

Comment: That could also work and i doubt it would be more demanding. Maybe edit your texture so it has a transparent background with stars in it.

Comment: Still, I am really hessitant to use that, as I believe a tile system would be best...  
I will be keeping this thread up in case someone stumbles upon it and helps. Until then I will use a temp fix.

Comment: Does my solution only show you the texture once or does the texture repeat itself? And note that there should be only 1 spriteBatch.Draw call in your draw method.